# Ability to show the number of followers a user has

Tags: feature-request

Currently it seems that users can be followed by subscription to their RSS feed. It would be awesome if the number of followers each user has is displayed somewhere on the site.

Comment: Seriously? You can ***follow* users**? *Why?*

Answer (score 5):

On your profile, right above the flag weight we already have `X views`.

We already have reputation to sort out the people that do their best, but why should we have followers on top of that? It's not even a reliable statistic given that you can fake RSS followers or that readers like Google Reader combine the RSS feed that several users have added under one request...

Sorting people just based on popularity is not what we want.

Comment: I think that people who are widely followed provide useful services both to their followers, and to the site. It would help if they were pre-selected and sorted, so that I, as someone who is interested in what they have to say, can quickly find them.

Comment: @blueberryfields: And why exactly is [reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) not good enough?

Comment: I am looking to follow someone who does *interesting* work on the site, not someone who does *good* work.

Comment: @blueberryfields: Follower counts do not denote how interesting someone is. Just because Rebecca Black has 127,000 subscribers, that doesn't make her more or less interesting than someone that has more or less subscribers. Just because I made some interesting posts, it doesn't mean that all my posts are interesting...